# Copy constructor and composition

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have a relationship of composition between class A and B,

```
class A
{
    A(); //default constructor  //EDIT
    A(const A &mA); // copy constructor //EDIT
    virtual ~A();
};


class B
{
B(A *pA); //constructor
B(const B &mB) //copy constructor
virtual ~B(); //EDIT: destructor to eliminate mA and to build the composition
A* mA;
};
```

Could I write the copy constructor in this manner:

```
B(const B &mB, A *pA)
```

I need it to keep up the composition also between the copied objects.
Is it wrong? Does it exist a better solution?
Thank you

EDIT: I'll try to explain me better. I want a copy of the object mB and the object mA. But if in the copy constructor I had writen mA =mB.mA I would copy the adress to the original object mA. So I think I need a deep copy not an swallow copy. My confusion arise because now, from the main, first I copy the object mA and then I copy mB. Doing that, I think I need to assign the copied object mA with an external function like

```
foo(A *pA)
```

Otherwise I could solve the problem if I could doing a deep copy of mB. Is this called a deep copy?

P.S.
A and B are abstract classes

Comment: You can write that function, but it's not the copy constructor.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: That should probably be an answer...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I don't have a better solution though(because I'm not exactly sure what he's trying to solve), and I think that's the meat of the question anyway.

Comment: Yeah, what problem are you trying to solve Ale?

Comment: @DavidGrayson: I want to copy B and its members data but I also want to assign another mA. So i defined a copy constructor to copy whole B without assingning mA. Now i don't know how to assign mA.

Comment: Why are all your destructors pure-virtual? You won't be able to instantiate *any* of those classes.

Comment: Please add much more information about your class design. Composition implies that your `A` object is destroyed as soon as its owning `B` object is destroyed, which your code doesn't do.

If you want value semantics for `mA` (i.e., copying a `B` object should copy its `A` object), consider using a value member (make `mA` to have type `A`).

Otherwise, consider using `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` for `mA`, depending on whether you need copying and shared ownership. Often you can get along without copying.

Comment: @KerrekSB: The classes are abstracts, so I edited the code to destroy the obj mA in the base class and to realize a composition.

Comment: @Philipp: Yes, the destructor delete the mA objects when the destructor of B is called so I could realize a composition

Comment: @Ale: I still don't understand whether you want the object that `mA` points to to be copied or not. If you want it to be copied, you have the problem that you don't know the dynamic type; you usually solve this by making base classes noncopyable and adding a virtual `Clone` member function. Otherwise, use `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @Philipp: I edited my question. Yes, I want to copy the object mA but not the adress of mA (mA is a pointer to the object of A). Is it called a deep copy?

Comment: @Ale: Yes, that can be called deep copying. The problem there is that `A` is an abstract class, but you need to copy an instance concrete subclass, but since you don't know which copy constructor to invoke, you need an abstract `Clone()` function. I'll post a detailed answer a bit later.

Comment: @Philipp: yes, i have just implemented a Clone() function. But i don't know if the rules of this forum require to update my original question or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  By definition, the copy constructor can not have a signature like the one you described.  Here are some valid signatures for copy constructors:

```
B(const B &);
B(B &);   // Thanks Oli!
```

Why do you need it?   You can access the mA member inside the copy constructor by doing something like this (I might have made some syntax errors):

```
B::B(const B & original)
{
    mA = original.mA;
}
```

Comment: To be pedantic, there are a couple of other valid signatures for a copy constructor (e.g. `B(B &)`).

Comment: That's not the definition of a copy constructor so "By definition" isn't accurate. E.g. `B(const B &mB, A *pA = 0)` would be a copy constructor.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: There are more than a couple of other valid signatures, the possibilities are virtually unlimited.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Good point, I hadn't considered default arguments.

Comment: For completeness sake, you may want to mention the rule of three, and  suggest supplying `B`'s assignment operator.

Comment: @ David Grayson I don't want to copy mA. I want to assign another object. Is it better to pass throught a function like foo(A *pA){point=pA)?

Comment: @Ale: If you want to assign another object, then you aren't copying.  So it sounds like the copy constructor is not what you should be looking at.

Comment: @Ale:  You don't have to exactly copy my code.  I was just showing that you can access the mA from the original if you want.  You can change my code and do whatever you want with `original.mA` and set `this->mA` to whatever you want.

Comment: @Oli:  I think Ale was just objecting to the copying of mA, not the overall concept of copying a B object.  Depending on his application, it might make sense to copy mA or to instead allocate a new A object when the B object is copied.

Comment: @everybody: You are too fast for my brain..thanks you. I need to take some hours to think about your good answers.

Comment: @Ale when you figure it out, please consider clicking the check mark next to my answer to accept it.

Comment: @DavidGrayson: I think the solution is: `mA = original.mA->clone()`; i am not sure how to use this site, Do I have to check your answer? Clone is a function implemented in the derivated class of A:`derA*derA::clone() const{
  return new derA(*this);
}`

Comment: @Ale ok sounds good.  You don't have to accept (click the check mark for) my answer but you should if you think it answers your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You might be overthinking this. The copy constructor simply needs to initialize all members to the corresponding values of the source object, e.g. like so:

```
B(B const & rhs) : mA(rhs.mA) { }
```

This is just the trivial copy, though, so if there's nothing else to it, then you'd better not write any copy constructor at all.

On the other hand, if you want a *deep* copy, it could be something like this:

```
B(B const & rhs) : mA(::new A(rhs.mA)) { }
```

However, the details of that depend on the actual ownership policy of class `B` with regard to the pointee `mA`. Depending on those details, don't forget to write an appropriate destructor, if necessary.

You should also write a matching assignment operator of your copy constructor does something non-trivial, for example:

```
B & operator=(B const & rhs)
{
    if (this != &rhs)
    {
        A * tmp = ::new A(*rhs.mA);    // need try/catch in general!
        ::delete mA; // OK, no exception occurred if we got here
        mA = tmp;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes!  Good point!  Clearly I was thinking of the assignment operator. (Although `B b(b)` will probably compile...)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I will declare `B b(b);` as "UB because of PEBKC" and not bother.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I also added the ass.operator for fun. It's even more self-assignment proof that strictly necessary :-)

Comment: I'd prefer `B& operator=(B const & rhs) { B tmp( rhs ); std::swap( mA, tmp.mA ); }`. Copy and swap style is a good fit for this situation.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Interesting option. It works in this case, but in general it'd require you to build a proper `swap` function for your class, non? And then I'd go all the way and say `B & operator=(B rhs) { swap(std::move(rhs)); }` Putting the burden of the copy on the caller :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: I write a lot of C++03 code and in this case, the copy is so important that I want to make it explicit and I also prefer it to be made in the body of `op=`, especially if the copy constructor and copy assignment operator are both non-inline. Yes, there's a potential performance gain that I may be doing without when, say, assigning an rvalue expression, but it's never been important enough to warrant the `op=(X x)` form for me.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes, you should usually have a non-throwing, constant-time `swap` if you have a custom (or disabled) copy constructor. In C++11, `std::swap` is often good enough (assuming that you have a non-throwing, constant-time move constructor), but in C++03, you have to take care of this yourself.
Your version of copy-and-swap is the best one (works for copy and move assignment, more efficient, shorter), but don't use `std::move` there; `swap` takes care of moving already.

Comment: @Philipp: Yes, good point about `move` inside `swap` - I seem to have a hard time remembering this one :-S

Comment: I need a deep copy but A is an abstract class. I can't instantiate it.